# Como introducir los objetos apropiadamente?

Tags: javascript

lo que sucede es que estoy creando un objeto llamando `clanes`, dentro del cual estan todos los clanes, en un array `clan`, y otro con sus *supuestos dueños*, pero como puedo saber, que, en el caso de mi ejemplo, el clan `'DW'` , pertenece a `'Javier'` ?

```js
var clanes = {
  name: [],
  owner: []
  
};


function crear(clan, owner) {
  
  var c = clan.toString();
  var d = owner;
  
  clanes.name.push(clan);
  clanes.owner.push(d);
  
}

crear("DW", "Javier")
crear("ZT", "Pedro")
console.info(clanes);
```

Se me ocurrió algo como recorrer todas las propiedas del objeto, y ya que todos son arrays, si tienen el mismo indice ha encontrado al dueño ,pero nosé no me aclaro..

***Intenté esto:***

```
var dueño = "";

for(var i in clanes) {
  if(clanes.name[i] == clanes.owner[i]) {

    dueño = clanes.owner[i];
    console.info("El dueño de :" + clanes.name[i] + " es: " + dueño);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensaya de esta forma, me parece que es mas apropiada para lo que necesitas. Acá no se están usando dos arreglos por separado para almacenar la información. Solo estoy usando un arreglo donde cada ítem dentro de ese arreglo posee el objeto con la información necesaria para cada clan:

```js
var clanes = [];

function crear(clan, owner) {
  clanes.push({name:clan,owner:owner});
}

crear("DW", "Javier");
crear("ZT", "Pedro");

console.info(clanes);

for(var i in clanes) {      
    console.info("El dueño de :" + clanes[i].name + " es: " + clanes[i].owner);
}
```

Comment: muchas graciaas¡!!!